# Остаться одному/одним

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

И в разговорной, и в письменной речи почти всегда используется "***остаться одному***", но ведь по-хорошему правильно должно быть "***остаться*** *(каким?/кем?)* ***одним***". А если в середину фразы вставить наречие ***совсем***, то "***остаться совсем одним***" даже начинает слух резать (на мой субъективный взгляд).

Тот же самый вопрос к фразе "***мне нужно побыть одному***". Будто слово ***одному*** согласуется по падежу со словом ***мне***, в то время как "***одному***" должно быть зависимым от "***мне***" словом в творительном падеже, а не в дательном: **Нужно** *(что сделать?)* **побыть** *(кому?)* **мне** *(кем?/каким?)* **одним**/человеком/идиотом/(кем угодно, но в творительном падеже). В случае с "***остаться одной***" формы творительного и дательного падежей совпадают, и сравнение не провести.

Также есть такие варианты как "***я хочу остаться один / я хочу побыть один***", но здесь ясности больше, так как употребление аналогично выбору между фразами "***он был хороший / он был хорошим***" - смысл кардинально не меняется, но именительный падеж указывает на постоянство признака или на большую длительность.

Хотел бы узнать, как всё же будет правильно, и с чем связана особенность такого употребления данных выражений?

UPD: имею в виду именно в значении "остаться в одиночестве" во всех перечисленных выше примерах.
Например: ***остаться одним в старости*** = ***остаться одиноким в старости***; ***остаться одному в старости*** = ***остаться одинокому в старости***. В последнем равенстве совсем другой смысл.

UPD2: спасибо большое **behemothus**, **Sharon**, **Alex_ander**, **grizzly** за развернутые ответы и аргументацию с приведением источников. Могу только один ответ пометить галочкой, поставлю ее на сообщение **grizzly**, тк так приведены хорошие примеры похожего употребления обсуждаемых местоимений. Думаю для таких же нелингвистов, как я, этот ответ будет наиболее полезен, нисколько не умаляя ценность остальных объяснений.

Comment: Что такое «по-хорошему правильно»? В чём вопрос? В том, что когда все пишут «одному», надо ли писать не так?

Comment: @shampar , Как правильно с точки зрения грамматики русского языка, ибо "одному" не согласуется с глаголом по задаваемому вопросу: остаться каким?/кем? (человеком/рабочим/ученым/собой/одним и тд), а не остаться какому?/кому? (человеку/рабочему/ученому/себе/одному).
Также интересно откуда вообще взялся тут дательный падеж с его "одному" - этим падежом описывается совсем другой контекст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Тот же самый вопрос к фразе "мне нужно побыть одному". Будто слово **одному** согласуется по падежу со словом **мне**

Вы правы: в этом примере слово **одному** согласуется в падеже со словом **мне**.

Подобные вопросы подробно рассматриваются в следующем учебнике: Тестелец Я.Г. "Введение в общий синтаксис". В нём предложено выделить в особый грамматический класс (**плавающие определители**) следующие местоимения: *сам, один, весь, оба*. В учебнике много говорится о специфике местоимений этого класса. Правда, написан он не самым простым языком, но и одни только примеры посмотреть тоже может быть интересно. Я приведу здесь скан-копию одной страницы с правилами **согласования ПО** (здесь ПО — "плавающие определители", звёздочкой отмечены недопустимые формы [это стандартное обозначение у лингвистов]):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё можно посмотреть (менее подробно, без теории) примеры согласования в таких предложениях в "Русской грамматике" Н.Ю. Шведовой (§ 2017, "смысловое согласование").

Comment: *в этом примере слово одному согласуется в падеже со словом мне.*  Простите, но согласование есть вид подчинительной связи. Вы серьезно полагаете, что в этом примере не глагол управляет существительным (или наречием), а местоимение?

Comment: @behemothus Я понимаю, что концепция "плавающих определителей" может показаться слишком сложной (а доктор филологических наук [Тестелец Я.Г.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86,_%D0%AF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) недостаточно авторитетным), но посмотрите хотя бы у Н.Ю. Шведовой, что такое "местоименные распространители"

Comment: @grizzlly Вы, простите, вопрос поняли? Меня не интересует концепция, меня интересует использование **вами** (а не кем-то ещё) вполне  ***школьных*** понятий синтаксической связи. И мне кажется, что вы злостно нарушаете сложившуюся терминологию. Вы, конечно, вправе вводить свои собственные термины, но надо хотя бы предупреждать, что они противоречат общепринятым.

Comment: И пожалуйста, не посылайте мкня раз за разом туда не знаю куда, искать то, не знаю что. Есть одна единственная, конкретная ваша фраза, по которой я и задал вопрос. Чем тут может помочь Шведова? Не думаю, что она путается в понятиях "согласование" и "управление".  .

Comment: @behemothus Все необходимые цитаты (в которых объясняется, что с чем **согласуется**) я привёл в ответе. Конечно, Шведова не путает согласование и управление и называет это "смысловым **согласованием**". Я отвечаю не только вам, но и потенциальным посетителям, поэтому вполне вправе рекомендовать необходимую литературу (насчёт вас я и так знаю по опыту, что читать вы её не станете).

Comment: *Шведова ... называет *"смысловым согласованием"* - что и требовалось доказать.

Comment: *Я отвечаю не только вам* - мне вы не отвечаете, если не считать сделанного сквозь зубы признания, что согласования в школьном смысле тут нету. А что касается "потенциальных посетителей", то именно о них я и думаю, когда пытаюсь понять вашу манеру изложения.

Comment: @behemothus Итак,  в ответе сказано: «в этом примере слово одному согласуется в падеже со словом мне». Разве это неверно? У нас не существует термина «согласование в падеже»?  К примеру, приложения согласуются с существительным именно в падеже. Для глагола «остаться»  характерно управление Т.п. (остаться кем, каким). Поэтому совершенно очевидно, что в предложении «мне нужно остаться одному» глагол не управляет Д.п. местоимения «одному», но зато так же очевидно присутствует согласование в Д.падеже:  «мне – одному». Глагол там вообще ничем не управляет.

Comment: Так какие вопросы к участнику?  В чем тут «злостно нарушена устоявшаяся терминология»?  Такая жесткая риторика должна иметь серьезное обоснование.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118148/discussion-on-answer-by-grizzly---).

Comment: @behemothus честно говоря, вообще не понятно, в чем суть ваших замечаний здесь. Пожалуйста, поясняйте более развернуто и в менее экспрессивной форме свои мысли – иначе от такого комментирования мало пользы.

Comment: @grizzly, а учебник в интернете есть?

Comment: @Серж Прямой ссылки у меня нет. Сможете самостоятельно разобраться с [Либгеном](http://libgen.rs/search.php?req=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def)? Дайте, пжл, знать, если возникнут сложности — я дам подробные инструкции.

Comment: @Grizzli спасибо, разберусь!

Answer (score 4):

**Ответ исправлен** (теоретическая часть сокращена, сделаны дополнения по семантике)

*Остаться **одному** или остаться **одним**?*

Правильно:  ***Мне** нужно остаться **одному**. **Им** нужно остаться **одним**.* Значение: в одиночестве.

Пояснение

1. Местоимение «одному» является **дуплексивом** в именном сказуемом.
2. **О дуплексивах**

**Дуплексив** – это член предложения с двунаправленной связью.  Дуплексив  в общем случае связан с глаголом (управление падежом) и существительным/местоимением (согласование в роде и числе).

**Типичный пример** – это именная часть сказуемого: Он вернулся расстроенный/расстроенным. Здесь мы видим колебание в падеже (Т.п. или И.п.), то есть управление со стороны глагола **ФАКУЛЬТАТИВНОЕ.**

3. В приведенном примере предложение безличное, местоимение "мне" является субъетным носителем состояния в форме Д.п. (Д.п.  характерен для безличных предложений, глагол этот падеж не задает).

В данном случае (в значении **как**? – в одиночестве) **управление со стороны глагола ОТСУТСТВУЕТ**, тогда местоимение "один" **СОГЛАСУЕТСЯ** с субъектным местоимением "мне" в роде, числе и **ПАДЕЖЕ**.

Сравнить (в личном предложении): ***Он** хочет остаться **один**.* Также **полное согласование** с субъектным местоимением "он" в роде, числе и падеже.

3. Но местоимение «один» **может управляться глаголом**: *Ему хочется (он хочет) остаться (**каким**?) одним из лучших спортсменов.*

Здесь  местоимение  «один» входит в именную часть сказуемого:  управление Т.п. со стороны глагола и согласование в роде и числе с местоимением (в личном или безличном предложении).

**Вывод:** управление со стороны глагола отсутствует в одном случае и имеет место в другом, но **семантика** при этом различная: остаться (как?) одному или остаться (каким?) одним.

Comment: я уперся в первую же вашу фразу. Не понял, во-первых, на какой вопрос вы отвечаете и при чем тут дуплексивы, и во-вторых, какое точно определение дает Кустова понятию "дуплексив". Если верить вашим словам, то оно противоречит общепринятому. Вот ссылка. http://www.1variant.ru/content/uchebniki/russki-yazik/249.pdf где тут про дуплексив, на какой хотя бы странице?

Comment: А о том, как понимают дуплексив в обычной практике - см. здесь. https://literary.ru/literary.ru/readme.php?subaction=showfull&id=1206018568&archive=1206184486&start_from=&ucat=& Гркбо говоря, дуплексив это просто слуга дух господ. Он управляется глаголос и согласуется с имнным сленом. Но при этом ни о какой двунаправленности речь не идет.

Comment: У меня новое издание Кустовой (2013 года), там этот параграф помечен  как факультативный, в издании 2005 года его нет. Называется он "Члены предложения с двунаправленной связью", термин "дуплексивы" там назван. В частности там приводятся предложения: Пете страшно одному, Маше страшно одной.  Указано, что дуплексив в этом случае относится к детерминанту с субъектным значением.

Comment: @Sharon - Отличный ответ, поздравляю! Поясните ещё, почему нет согласования по падежу в предложениях: "Для меня тяжело быть одному/одним" и "Для меня тяжело быть расстроенным/расстроенному"

Comment: @Sharon То есть вы меня послали искать в сети то, чего там нет? Браво! ну вы хоть в состоянии  ответить, как понимает "дуплексив" Кустова со товарищи? Если так как вы передали, то это надо хотя бы оговорить. "Дуплексив – это член предложения с ***двунаправленной*** связью" - это утверждение вызывает вопросы. Поясните, что такое в вашем понимании "двунаправленная связь" и употребляет ли этот термин Кустова.

Comment: @user190920 можно я отвечу за @Sharon? Именно потому там и нет согласования, что согласования там нет по грамматике. А вообще о дуплексивах - см. тут. https://literary.ru/literary.ru/readme.php?subaction=showfull&id=1206018568&archive=1206184486&start_from=&ucat=&  **Про "согласования" там вообще ничего не говорится**. Тут или Кустова использует какое необычное значение термина, либо, что вернее, Sharon просто неверно поняла её, подогнав под свои идеи..

Comment: Вы минусуете мой ответ за неправильный адрес для книги? Это вы когда-то мне его прислали. А вот как выглядит мой экземпляр 2013 года, litres.ru/g-i-kustova/… Также я видела издания 2017 и 2019 года. В электронном виде их нет, но вы можете сделать заказ на бумажную книгу, которую пришлют в ваш ближайший магазин. Хотите, я вам ее подарю? Мне для вас ничего не жалко! Вы получите много удовольствия при ее прочтении. Будьте хотя бы немного добрее к себе и людям. Поздравляю Вас с Новым годом!

Comment: @Sharon, спасибо за ответ! Подскажите, если во фразе "Мне нужно остаться одному" глагол не задает дательный падеж, то получается, что "мне" играет роль подлежащего? И с наступившим вас Новым годом)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118204/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---).

Answer (score 3):

Ответ на комментарий

Спасибо за оценку! Где же вы только находите такие трудные вопросы?

ВОПРОС

Поясните, почему нет согласования по падежу в предложениях: "Для меня тяжело быть одному/одним" и "Для меня тяжело быть расстроенным/расстроенному"

ОТВЕТ

Предложения безличные. Вероятно, имеется в виду согласования в падеже с формой «для меня».

1. *Для меня (мне)  тяжело быть **расстроенным/одиноким, больным**.* В безличном предложении для прилагательного «расстроенный»  возможно **только управление** Т.п. со стороны глагола.

*Для меня (мне)  тяжело быть **одному**.* В безличном предложении для местоимения «один»  **управления Т.п. нет**, а выбор **Д.п.** связан с **обычной формой субъектного детерминанта «мне».**

2. Значит, слова «один» и «расстроенный» **ведут себя по-разному**, так что не зря выделяется эта **группа местоименных слов** (в том числе в ответе **grizzly**): ***сам, весь, один, каждый*** и др.  Эти слова в различных конструкциях сохраняют **форму в заданным смыслом.**
3. Сравним:

**(1) Для прилагательного «расстроенный»**

В двусоставном предложении  глагольное управление именной частью  возможно, но необязательно.  *Я пришел **расстроенным** (Т.п.)/**расстроенный** (И.п.).*  В безличном предложении глагольное управление становится обязательным:  *Для меня тяжело быть ***расстроенным**** (Т.п).

**(2) Для местоимения «один»**

*Я пришел **один**. Для меня (мне) тяжело быть **одному**.* Местоимение «один»  в значении «в одиночестве» **не допускает глагольное управление** в обоих предложениях, причем Д.п. в безличном предложении согласован с обычной формой субъектного детерминанта «мне».

Comment: я не знаю, кто  задал эти вопросы, но они явно по теме вашего ответа. К сожалению, неправильная постановка (с "почему") дала вам возможно по сути уйти от содержательного ответа.  Речь ведь о том, что утверждение о "согласовании", на которое вы упираете, на самом деле не имеет места.  Просто совпадение. Которое я объясняю тем, что обе формы управляются одним глаголом в одном значении. .

Comment: *Предложения безличные.* - исходное предложение тоже безличное. Но вы на голубом глазу утверждате безусловное наличие в нем согласования.

Answer (score 2):

**Инфинитив** не всегда *управляет* примыкающим словом. Управление произвольными падежами может быть обусловлено семантическими (*оставаться **одним из немногих***) или грамматическими (*оставаться в одиночестве*) причинами.

> *[Субъект инфинитивных предложений выражается **дательным** падежом](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6)*
>
> (см. 2.3.1.1. Дательный падеж при инфинитиве)

То есть, дательный падеж при инфинитиве исходит от *субъекта* инфинитивного предложения (от явного или подразумеваемого "**мне**","**ему**", "кому-то другому"). С ним в нашем случае и согласуется по падежу числительное: по семантическим причинам "сквозное" управление (**я один** -> **мне одному**) оказывается сильнее и *снимает управление от глагола* (глагол здесь может быть любым).

> **мне** (ему, тебе, Васе) **одному** [остаться (радоваться, кувыркаться и т.
> п.)]

> мне (**ей**, тебе, тёте) **одной** [несмотря на совпадение падежных форм,
> здесь падеж однозначно *дательный*, а не творительный]

> нам (им, **вам**,
> призракам) **одним** [дательный множ. числа] остаться

Comment: *Инфинитив не всегда управляет примыкающим словом*  - Alex_ander, мало нам путаницы в понятиях "согласование" и ""управление", так вы еще и примыкание притащили. Но помилуйте, всё это виды ***подчинительной*** связи. Что у вас чему тут подчиняется?

Comment: *Субъект инфинитивных предложений выражается дательным падежом* - а с эимт-то никто и не спорит. Но при чем здесь согласование? Наоборот такая постановка вопроса однозначно говорит, что субъект именно **управляется** инфинитивром.

Comment: Да, управляется. При этом управляет словом, примыкающим (здесь) к инфинитиву (передает ему свой падеж - мне одному, самому, босу, биту, белу, пушисту).

Comment: спасибо. Уточню, на всякий пожарный, что вы говорите именно о синтаксической связи, а не используете эти понятия в каком-то другом значении? Если да, то не могли бы ответить на отвелеченный вопрос? Какая синтаксическая связь у слов "большое" и "красное" в предложении ***"Большое красное яблоко лежало на столе"***? Или "Завершил трапезу большим красным яблоком"?  Вопрос для школы принципиальный, за это на экзамене могут выносят. без звука.

Comment: Добавлю что согласование по дательному падежу может быть не обязательно или даже ошибкой: "Мне не к лицу быть расстроенным/расстроенному"

Comment: @user190920 В примере _из вопроса_ возможен только дательный падеж, но я привел и случай ("одним из немногих"), когда управление от инфинитива передается не только его субъекту (дательный падеж, как и должно быть), но и напрямую последующей конструкции (творительный). В вашем примере такое же управление. От чего это зависит? Не от семантики глагола (на месте глагола "быть" возможен другой). То, что имеет место в случае с "один"  (передача дательного падежа от субъекта инфинитива), не распространяется на _полные прилагательные_ (расстроенный, одинокий, единственный).

Comment: Иначе обстоит с _краткими_ прилагательными (в предыдущем комменте я привел несколько таких) - некоторые могут склоняться и оказываются в дательном падеже. Условно можно адаптировать под краткую (пусть и архаичную) форму и ваш пример (Мне не к лицу быть расстроену - ср.: одиноку).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь речь идет не о том *кем* остаться, а о том *кому* остаться. Сравните:

- `Нужно остаться одному.`
- `Нужно остаться мне.`
- `Нужно остаться Ивану.`
- `Нужно остаться двоим.`
- `Нужно остаться детям.`

Во всех этих примерах *кому-то* нужно/хочется/приходится остаться.

То есть нет сохранения какого-то состояния—в этом случае было бы, действительно, `одним` и творительный падеж—`Ивану нужно остаться одним из лучших.`

Можете также сравнить аналогичные согласования с другими глаголами и другими количествами:

- `Остаться одному` и `Решить самому`
- `Остаться двоим` и `Решить самим`

В частности, попробуйте совместить две эти фразы:

`Дайте ему побыть одному и самому решить, что дальше делать.`

Comment: Если имеется в виду "остаться в одиночестве", то дательный падеж ведь совсем не подходит, однако на практике почти всегда встречается "остаться одному", когда имеют в виду именно "остаться в одиночестве".
Например: остаться одним (одному?) в старости - остаться в одиночестве в старости. Тут очень тяжело обосновать управление дательным падежом.

Answer (score -1):

> Остаться одному/одним

Оба варианта правильны. Это два разных значения, чуть ли не противоположных по смыслу..

***Остаться (в каком состоянии?) одному - в одиночестве,

Остаться (кем?) одним [тех, кто... ] - напротив, пребывать в некоторой группе.***

Надо отметить, что выражение "остаться одному" возможно только в такой, безличной форме со значением категории состояния или модального предикатива (тяжело остаться одному, придется остаться одному), в личных формах заменяется на "один" (в соотвветвующем числе и роде).

*Вы же очень много пишете и не приводите содержательных примеров, поэтому просто перемудрили.*

> *Будто слово одному согласуется по падежу со словом мне, в то время как "одному" должно быть зависимым от "мне"*

Здесь "одному" в значении предиката (наречном или категории состояния), поэтому ни с чем согласовываться не должно в принципе. Да и вообще разберитесь в терминах синтаксической связи. Глагол **управляет** дополнением, а **согласование** возможно, например, между подлежащим и сказуемым. Я не могу представить форму "одному" в предлоджении с двумя главными членами. То есть все ваши рассуждения о каком-то "согласовании" просто изначально неверны.

ПС, если вопрос не на понимание, а на формальное знание, с точным объяснением лучше дождаться кого-то из практикующих или практиковавших преподавателей.

(++) ====
О дательном падеже в безличных предложениях есть у Валгиной И Розенталя
http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-157.htm

К сожалению, адаптированные источники обычно ограничивются упоминанием того, что дательный падеж в безличном предложении - вполне частая вещь. Но причины не разбирают. А на самом деле тут можно глкбоко в имторическую грамматику залезть, если вспомнить, что современный русский инфинив - потомок дательного падежа особого отглагольного существительного.

(++) ====

У меня вопросы ко всем, утверждающим, что "Ему" согласовывается с формой "одному".
Согласование (в синтаксическом смысле) предполагает наличие основного слова, от которого идет вопрос к подчиненному. И это не изменить никакими ссылками на "дуплексивы" (а что оно такое вообще?).
~1. Какой тут вопрос? Неужели "какому?"
~2. Уберите "ему" из фразы. ***Тяжело оставаться одному.***  С чем тут согласуется "одному"?! В словосочетании с синтаксической связью удаление из фразы главного слова сочетания убивает грамматику. Тут этого не происходит.

Поскольку вопросу наполовину риторические, делаю вывод. ***Утверждение о наличии согласования (как вида синтаксической связи!) между "ему" и "одному" неверно изначально.***

Говорить о какой-то семантической связи и тем более "дуплексивах" не буду в силу того, что пока нет возможности убедиться, что именно под этим понимают авторы. Во всяком случае явно не то, о чем спрашивали.

На мой взгляд глагол "отаваться" здесь управляет как формой "ему", так и формой "одному". Поэтому они и совпадают в падеже. Но не более того, говорить о согласовании нут неуместно.

(+++) ====

И все-таки о "дуплексивах". Не имея возможности увидеть тот текст, о котором говорит @Sharon, но исходя из смысла выражения двунаправленная связь, могу лишь предположить, что двунаправленная связь усматривается в сочетании типа "ему одному" - здесь за главное слово можно выбрать любое, которое и согласуется с другим в роде и числе. Но это ошибочное представление, поскольку в данном случае "ему одному" не является словосочетанием и говорить о наличии синтаксической связи неправильно.

(+++) ====

> Дуплексив - это особый тип второстепенного члена предложения, который
> связан с двумя членами предложения (глагольным и именным), отвечает на
> вопрос обстоятельства или дополнения, характеризуется двумя значениями -
> обстоятельства и определения или дополнения и определения и выражается
> именем прилагательным, именем существительным, реже -
> другими частями речи (именем числительным, местоимением, причастием).

https://literary.ru/literary.ru/readme.php?subaction=showfull&id=1206018568&archive=1206184486&start_from=&ucat=&

Пока не будет другого содержательного и однозначного понимаемого определения, буду трактовать этот термин так и только так.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ! Раз "одному" - предикатив, то тогда я изначально был неправ в своих рассуждениях о падежах и тд; плюс, как вы и сказали, в терминологии наошибался. Теперь вопросов не осталось.

Comment: @Axelay *Раз "одному" - предикатив*  - не совсем так. Во фразе "тяжело остаться одному" предикатив - "Тяжело". А одному выступает в качестве наречия при нем. Впрочем, тут лучше преподавателя привлечь, а то я вас запутать могу. Я, пожалуй, задам этот вопрос отдельно...

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463026

Comment: 1) «согласование возможно, например, между подлежащим и сказуемым» -- приведите пример, пожалуйста; 2) «Глагол управляет дополнением» -- выходит, по-вашему, граммему рода «одному» получает от глагола... Это чудеса какие-то, так управление не работает, насколько мне известно. Глагол в управлении может максимум сообщать падеж, но в нормальном случае никак уж не род. 3) «Здесь "одному" в значении предиката» -- что такое «в значении»? Это, по-вашему, предикат или не предикат этого предложения? 4) Известно ли вам понятие Pro-drop?

Comment: "Aer 1) Петя Любит Машу. - Согласование идет в роде и числе. 2) Я не комментирую, что там у вас выходит. Я такого не говорил. Я вообще термин граммема не употреблял бы здесь за его неоднознгачностью. А форма "одному" здесь требуется в силу наличия управляющего глагола "остваваться". *Глагол в управлении может максимум сообщать падеж* - именно так. А мы о чем? 3) Не могу ответить содержательно "в знчении" есть первичное понятие, выходящее за рамки филологических тем. Можете заменить на "в функции предиката". 4) Нет. Вопрос не по теме.

Comment: @Aer  Я все-таки отвечу на "Pro-drop". А Вам известна формула *idem per idem*?  Конечно же, я понимаю о чем идет речь. Чешский язык вообще почти не употребляет местоимений.  Но с какого боку тут это? Своей отсылкой к pro-drop вы **постулируете** наличие синтаксической связи между "ему" и "одному"  - а это именно то, против чего я возражаю. Какой смысл доказывать то, что взято вами за постулат?

Comment: @behemothus спасибо за ваш ответ. 1) Вы сами говорили, что согласование – подчинительная связь. Что что подчиняет в паре подлежащее – сказуемое? Как известно, ситуация гораздо сложнее, и не стоит называть это согласованием – во всяком случае таким же чистым, как и _красивая петля_. 2) Объясните тогда, пожалуйста, откуда «одному» получает мужской род? Про pro-drop пока не буду отвечать, подожду вашего ответа, если вы не против.

Comment: Вопрос про форму «одному» имеет прямое отношение к теме, и мне очень жаль, что вы не можете пояснить свою точку зрения на него.

Comment: @Aer я уже пояснил свою точку зрения. см. ответ на pro-drop. Своими  первыми четырьмя вопросами вы трижды исказили мою мысль, но я постарался ответить содкдержательно, насколько это позволяла обстановка. Сейчас делаете это в четвертый раз. Я вообще не говорил, что *одному* "получает род". Это **ваш** постулат. А по мне так если и "получает" то из контекста. От мужского рода объекта, если угодно. И вообще мы не о "получении", а о согласовании. Понимаете разницу?

Comment: Ваше пояснение «от мужского рода объекта, если угодно», вероятно, противоречит вашему ответу «"одному"... ни с чем согласовываться не должно в принципе»: получение формой _одному_ значения м. р. от «объекта» и есть согласование. В синтаксическом дереве при отсутствии материально выраженного «объекта» будет постулироваться нуль, cf. pro-drop. Конечно, можно не принимать нули, но отрицать факт _зависимости_ (выявляемой в согласовании, например) _одному_ от некоторого элемента в м. р. – позиция весьма поверхностная.

Comment: А то, что вы не говорили, откуда _одному_ получает род, как раз печальный факт, который делает ваш ответ в моих глазах неубедительным. Ведь поэтому и спрашиваю :)

Comment: @Aer *как раз печальный факт, который делает ваш ответ в моих глазах неубедительным* - не собираюсь это обсуждать как и все остальное.

Comment: @Aer *Противоречит вашему ответу «"одному"... ни с чем согласовываться не должно в принципе»* Это ваше мнение. Вы подменили понятия.

Comment: А разговоры про синтаксическое дерево - это вообще не про мой ответ. Откуда "получает" свой род слово "ему" в нашем примере?! От печального факта? ))))

Comment: Ему — от антецедента.

Comment: @Aer *Ему — от антецедента* - вот это я и назвал контекстом. ))) "одному" - оттуда же. Неужели вы думаете, что использование умного слово (принадлежащего, кстати, отнюдь не общепринятой системе взглядов) что-то изменит? Вы постулируете здесь применимость pro-теории - и требуете от меня, чтобы я вам отвечал в её рамках. А я не придерживаюсь вообще этой системы взглядов И уж точно не обсуждаю её не в контексте исходного вопроса ответа.  Впрочем, спасибо, Ваше упорство становится понятным. Вы подгоняете факты под понравившуюся вам теорию.

Comment: Нет, я совершенно не настаиваю на какой-либо теории, просто вы не можете убедительно описать м. р. на форме _одному_. Pro-drop -- может. _Одному_ -- это, в общем, прилагательное, у него нет антецедента. Так что, конечно, «"одному" - оттуда же» -- если вы правда так считаете -- не выдерживает никакой критики.

Comment: *просто вы не можете убедительно описать м. р. на форме одному* - я так не думаю. Насчет теории. Посмотрите, хотя бы в той же вики, что такое антецедент - и у каких частей речи он бывает. Я опускаю все прочие нелепости вашего изложения. А что касается объяснений через pro-drop, то оно не выдерживает критики, во всяком в таком виде.  Я уэе два раза сказал, что вы здесь впадаетет в логическую ошибку idem per idem. Вы **постулитуете** наличие какой-то синтаксичекой связи на основании этой теории pro-drop. А потом через эту теорию эту связь и доказываете.

Comment: Мало того что это замкнутый круг, это просто неверно по сути. ему одному - не является в данном примере словосочетанием и наличие вертикальной связи не просматривается. Здесь не более чем совпадение в падеже и роде. Что объясняется единым объектом.