# (остаться) одному - грамматический разбор

Tags: грамматика

В продолжение вопроса
[Остаться одному/одним](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463022)

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать "школьный" грамматический разбор предложений типа:

**"Я остался один"** и **"Мне тяжело одному".**

Интересует прежде всего то, как в школе объяснили бы изменение формы у числительного(?) "один" в наречном значении. Да и вообще, какая это часть речи тут?

А то меня в стремлении к точности в такие дебри занесло, где я откровенно "плаваю".

Comment: Да вроде бы был у Вас подход к «одному» не как числительному, а  как местоимению, практически существительному.

Comment: @shampar вы неточно мою мысль передаете, но вопрос-то не в этом. Я хочу услышать, как трактуют эту ситуацию представитель разных школ. В вопросе, на который я ссылаюсь четыре участника имеют пять попарно взаимоисключающих точек зрения. И самое обидное. что минимум двое ссылаются на заведомо непроверяемые источники, предлагая взамен точных цитат свою, довольно сомнительную интерпретацию как непреложный факт..

Comment: Что же касается моего мнения, то я говорил, что это слово здесь выступает в роли наречия, хотя грамматически оно скорее прилагательное. Причем в первом предложении оно куда больше прилагательное, чем наречие, во-втором - наоборот. Но это все я хотел бы услышать именно от представителей разных школ передовой мысли. А то у школьника от всего этого потока сознания просто когнитивный диссонанс может случиться.